# How can I handle new line character using java-util-scanner in this situation?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I have a simple homework assignment, I'm making a simple UI (not GUI) and I'm using scanner for input.

I want to read 3 strings (Name, address, social security number)

If the user however does not insert anything simply presses enter, my code breaks. Instead of the 3 strings I need, I get more strings and they miss match.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
if (input.hasNext()) {
    name = input.nextLine(); 
} 
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
if (input.hasNext()) {
    address = input.nextLine(); 
} 
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
if (input.hasNext()) {
    ssnumb = input.nextLine(); 
}
```

So if user presses enter, creates a new line character, the input spills. How can I either avoid this or eliminate empty lines ?

**Example:**

*enter*

Nick

Mars

*some number*

**I would have:**

`Name:`

`Address:` Nick

`Social Security Number:` Mars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while(!input.next().isEmpty()) { // only when you enter literal string 
//do your scanner stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = "";
while(name.trim().isEmpty()) {
    name = input.next();
}
```